Should CqlSesstion be annotated with @ApplicationScoped?
I noticed that Springboot exposes CqlSession as a bean with default scope (one bean per context).
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/c3c82bd220b39998e5dc483db55532092ace1b3b/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.java#L105-L110
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    @Lazy
    public CqlSession cassandraSession(CqlSessionBuilder cqlSessionBuilder) {
        return cqlSessionBuilder.build();
    }

At the same time Cassandra documentation states:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.9/manual/core/

CqlSession ... It is thread-safe, you should create a single instance (per target Cassandra cluster), and share it throughout your application

So wouldn't it make sense to annotate CqlSession with @ApplicationScoped?

I agree that annotating with @ApplicationScoped makes sense since the CqlSession bean should only ever be created once. Cheers!
